# Failed connect to telegram with telethon

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

My code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, connection
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='[%(levelname) 5s/%(asctime)s] %(name)s: %(message)s',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)

api_id = 1234567
api_hash = '1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef'

client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
```

I'm trying to connect to telegram via a telethon, but I always get this error:

> [DEBUG/2020-06-05 11:40:42,860] asyncio: Using selector: SelectSelector
>   [ INFO/2020-06-05 11:40:43,006] telethon.network.mtprotosender: Connecting to 1.1.1.1:111/TcpFull...
>   [DEBUG/2020-06-05 11:40:43,009] telethon.network.mtprotosender: Connection attempt 1...
>   [WARNING/2020-06-05 11:40:53,011] telethon.network.mtprotosender: Attempt 1 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
>   [DEBUG/2020-06-05 11:40:54,024] telethon.network.mtprotosender: Connection attempt 2...
>   [WARNING/2020-06-05 11:41:04,026] telethon.network.mtprotosender: Attempt 2 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
>   [DEBUG/2020-06-05 11:41:05,059] telethon.network.mtprotosender: Connection attempt 3...
>   [WARNING/2020-06-05 11:41:15,061] telethon.network.mtprotosender: Attempt 3 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
>   [DEBUG/2020-06-05 11:41:16,084] telethon.network.mtprotosender: Connection attempt 4...
>   [WARNING/2020-06-05 11:41:26,086] telethon.network.mtprotosender: Attempt 4 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
>   [DEBUG/2020-06-05 11:41:27,088] telethon.network.mtprotosender: Connection attempt 5...
>   [WARNING/2020-06-05 11:41:37,076] telethon.network.mtprotosender: Attempt 5 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
>   [DEBUG/2020-06-05 11:41:38,079] telethon.network.mtprotosender: Connection attempt 6...
>   [WARNING/2020-06-05 11:41:48,093] telethon.network.mtprotosender: Attempt 6 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\cfc.py", line 11, in 
>       client.start()
>     File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 132, in start
>       else self.loop.run_until_complete(coro)
>     File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 579, in run_until_complete
>       return future.result()
>     File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 139, in _start
>       await self.connect()
>     File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 478, in connect
>       proxy=self._proxy
>     File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 125, in connect
>       await self._connect()
>     File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 250, in _connect
>       raise ConnectionError('Connection to Telegram failed {} time(s)'.format(self._retries))
>   ConnectionError: Connection to Telegram failed 5 time(s)

Comment: Have you replaced the api_id and api_hash pair with a valid one from https://my.telegram.org?

Comment: @Tibebes. M  Yes, I did.

Comment: Could it be because its limited in your location maybe? Try using a proxy/vpn and see if it works.

Comment: @Tibebes.M, I checked it through 2 vpns and it doesn't work yet...

Answer (score 2):

to whom may concern! you need to add a proxy parameter to your TelegramClient

```
import socks
proxy = (socks.SOCKS5, 'your socks proxy IP', 'your socks proxy port')
TelegramClient(proxy=proxy, 'add other required arguments')
```